# Magento 2: Custom Conditions Rule in Custom Module Validation

Tags: magento2, customer, sales-order, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have created a custom module contain two sections:

The first section contains **title(text Field),icon(Uploader) and custom dropdown** ,the second section contains **conditions rule**.

In this module was added new conditions rule named **Total Sales (Life Time Sales)** for customer.

***My Question***: **How to use this condition and validate it in my module?**

> /app/Vendor/Modulename/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="salesrule_rule_condition_combine">
        <observer instance="Vendor\Modulename\Observer\Salesrule\RuleConditionCombine" name="cart_rule_total_sales"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> /app/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component/custom_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="general">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <field formElement="input" name="title" sortOrder="20">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Modulename</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Title</label>
            <dataScope>title</dataScope>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    </field>

    <field name="icon">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Modulename</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Icon</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="route/modulename/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="discount">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Discount</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Discount(%)</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">discount</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="filter_by">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Filterby</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Filter By</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filter_by</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>

<fieldset name="conditions_serialized">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="conditions_apply_to" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Label\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

> /app/Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Label\Edit\Tab\Conditions

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Label\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic 
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_nameInLayout = 'conditions_serialized';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * The getter function to get the new RuleFactory dependency
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getRuleFactory()
    {
        if ($this->ruleFactory === null) {
            $this->ruleFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory');
        }
        return $this->ruleFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_SALES_RULE);
        $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of conditions tab to supplied form.
     *
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $model
     * @param string $fieldsetId
     * @param string $formName
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_serialized', $formName = 'custom_form')
    {
        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = $this->getRuleFactory()->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'sales_rule/promo_quote/newConditionHtml/form/' . $conditionsFieldSetId,
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $newChildUrl
        )->setFieldSetId(
            $conditionsFieldSetId
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            $fieldsetId,
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            [
                'name'           => 'conditions',
                'label'          => __('Conditions'),
                'title'          => __('Conditions'),
                'required'       => true,
                'data-form-part' => $formName
            ]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of form name to condition and its conditions.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions
     * @param string $formName
     * @return void
     */
    private function setConditionFormName(\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions, $formName)
    {
        $conditions->setFormName($formName);
        if ($conditions->getConditions() && is_array($conditions->getConditions())) {
            foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
                $this->setConditionFormName($condition, $formName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> /app/Vendor/Modulename/Observer/Salesrule/RuleConditionCombine.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Observer\Salesrule;

class RuleConditionCombine implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $additional = $observer->getAdditional();
        $conditions = (array) $additional->getConditions();

        $conditions = array_merge_recursive($conditions, [
            $this->getTotalSalesRuleCondition()
        ]);

        $additional->setConditions($conditions);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total sales rule conditions.
     * @return array
     */
    private function getTotalSalesRuleCondition()
    {
        return [
            'label'=> __('Total Sales'),
            'value'=> \Vendor\Modulename\Model\Rule\Condition\Totalsales::class
        ];
    }
}
```

> /app/Vendor/Modulename/Model/Rule/Condition/Totalsales

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model\Rule\Condition;

/**
 * Class Totalsales
 */
class Totalsales extends \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $orderFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Load attribute options
     * @return $this
     */
    public function loadAttributeOptions()
    {
        $this->setAttributeOption([
            'total_sales' => __('Total Sales')
        ]);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get input type
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInputType()
    {
        return 'string';
    }

    /**
     * Get value element type
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValueElementType()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    /**
     * Get value select options
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    public function getValueSelectOptions()
    {
        $opt = [];
        if ($this->hasValueOption()) {
            foreach ((array)$this->getValueOption() as $key => $value) {
                $opt[] = ['value' => $key, 'label' => $value];
            }
        }
        return $opt;
    }

    /**
     * Validate Total Sales Rule Condition
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
    {
        $customerId = $model->getCustomerId();
        $lifetimesales = $this->getLifetimeSalesByCustomer($customerId);
        $model->setData('total_sales', $lifetimesales);
        return parent::validate($model);
    }

    /**
     * getLifetimeSalesByCustomer
     * @param integer $customer_id
     * @return float            
     */
    protected function getLifetimeSalesByCustomer($customer_id)
    {   
        //Get Object Manager Instance
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Sale\Collection');
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE)));
        $_collection->setOrderStateFilter(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)
        ->setCustomerIdFilter($customer_id)
        ->load();
        $customerLifetimeSales = $_collection->getTotals();
        $lifetime = $customerLifetimeSales['lifetime'];
        return $lifetime;
    }
}
```

> /app/Vendor/Modulename/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Start Total Sales Custom Rule Condition -->
    <type name="Vendor\Modulename\Model\Rule\Condition\Totalsales">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="form_name" xsi:type="string">sales_rule_form</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <!-- End Total Sales Custom Rule Condition -->
</config>
```

> Conditions Rule:

```
[rule] => Array
        (
            [conditions] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
                            [aggregator] => all
                            [value] => 1
                            [new_child] => 
                        )

                    [1--1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Vendor\Modulename\Model\Rule\Condition\Totalsales
                            [attribute] => total_sales
                            [operator] => >=
                            [value] => 1200
                        )

                    [1--2] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => vendor\Modulename\Model\Rule\Condition\Totalsales
                            [attribute] => total_sales
                            [operator] => <
                            [value] => 2400
                        )

                )

        )
```

> Conditions Rule Serialized:

```
a:3:{i:1;a:4:{s:4:"type";s:46:"Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine";s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:9:"new_child";s:0:"";}s:4:"1--1";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:51:"Vendor\Modulename\Model\Rule\Condition\Totalsales";s:9:"attribute";s:11:"total_sales";s:8:"operator";s:2:">=";s:5:"value";s:4:"1200";}s:4:"1--2";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:51:"Vendor\Modulename\Model\Rule\Condition\Totalsales";s:9:"attribute";s:11:"total_sales";s:8:"operator";s:1:"<";s:5:"value";s:4:"2400";}}
```

[image]